# Using boost multiprecision with trigonometric function

Tags: c++, boost, multiprecision

Consider the following code which creates a multiprecision floating-point number '***a***' by using boost.

How do I use boost library to invoke trigonometric functions? 
For example, I hope to calculate ***sin(a)***.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

typedef number<backends::cpp_bin_float<24, backends::digit_base_2, void, boost::int16_t, -126, 127>, et_off> float32;

int main (void) {
  float32 a("0.5");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to demonstrate where you're stuck. You're not exposing any problem you have. I've found it, but you didn't make it clear in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a limitation in the library. When the precision is dropped too low, the `sin` implementation no longer compiles.

Some intermediate calculations are being done in `double` precision. The assignment into the result type would be lossy and hence doesn't compile.

Your chosen type [actually corresponds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_bin_float.html) to `cpp_bin_float_single`. That doesn't compile.

As soon as you select `cpp_bin_float_double` (precision 53 binary digits) or higher, you'll be fine.

---

I suppose this limitation could be viewed as a bug in some respects. You might report it to the library devs, who will be able to judge whether the related code could use single-precision floats there without hurting the convergence of the `sin` approximation.

Comment: Thanks!  It tried using double precision and its worked. Well.... I am actually concerning about single precision. But, as you had mentioned, this is a different issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
int main() {
    cpp_bin_float_100 a = 1;
    cout << setprecision(50) << endl;
    cout << sin(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've verified digits with Wolfram Mathematica and they are correct:

[image]